# Subset from a list with relational operators

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list object that contains multiple lists with in each list the same returning objects. The list below is a short version of this.

```
logs <- list(list(success = TRUE, details = "check", timestamp = as.Date("2017-10-06")),
         list(success = FALSE, details = "uncheck", timestamp = as.Date("2017-10-07")),
         list(success = FALSE, details = "check", timestamp = as.Date("2017-10-08")),
         list(success = FALSE, details = "uncheck", timestamp = as.Date("2017-10-09")))
```

I want to create two vectors: one vector (success_true) that contains the content of the second element of each list if the content of the first element equals true, and one vector (succes_false) that contains the content of the second element of each list if the content of the first element equals false. The result that I'm looking for looks like this:

```
success_true <- c("check")
succes_false <- c("uncheck", "check", "uncheck")
```

The sapply solution that Shaun Wilkinson came up with works.

```
# Solution number 1 by Shaun Wilkinson: sapply
successes <- sapply(logs, function(e) e$success)
details <- sapply(logs, function(e) e$details)
success_true <- details[successes]
success_false <- details[!successes]
```

I also came up with another solution that incoorporates a conditional statement within a for loop.

```
# Solution number 2 by SHW: conditional statement with for loop
success_true <- c() #create two vectors
success_false <- c()

for (log in logs) { 
  if (log$success == TRUE) {
    success_true <- c(success_true, log$details) #add content of details element to the success_true vector if the condition is met
  } else {
    success_false <- c(succes_false, log$details) #add content of details element to the success_false vector if the condition is met
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Shauns answer, I have found another solution that incoorporates a conditional statement in a for loop. I think this solution allows for more flexibility and therefore is the solution that I will be using.

```
success_true <- c() #create two vectors
success_false <- c()

for (log in logs) { 
  if (log$success == TRUE) {
    success_true <- c(success_true, log$details) #add content of details element to the success_true vector if the condition is met
  } else {
    success_false <- c(succes_false, log$details) #add content of details element to the success_false vector if the condition is met
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
successes <- sapply(logs, function(e) e$success)
details <- sapply(logs, function(e) e$details)
success_true <- details[successes]
success_false <- details[!successes]
```

Comment: This solution works. Can you maybe elaborate a little on what you're doing in the code?

Comment: Sure, it's probably not the most elegant solution, but the first two lines just extract the 'success' and 'details' elements from the nested lists, and coerce them into a logical vector and a character vector, respectively. The second part is simply logical subsetting of the 'details' vector.